# How get all value from the header of a response?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, postman, http-post, web-frontend

I want autogenrated id of just inserted record through post request using angular and springboot.

I have a post request when i am hitting it from POSTMAN i am getting its id..

[image]

but when i am hitting same request angular and trying to get id then i am not getting

[image]

Here is my code of angular

```
save() {
    this.projectsCategoryService
    .createProjectsCategory(this.projectsCategory).subscribe((data:Response)=> {
      console.log(data)
      this.projectsCategory = new ProjectsCategory();
     
      console.log("posted data is "+data.url);
      this.submitted = true; 
      this.list();
      //this.gotoList();
    }, 
    error => console.log(error));
  }

createProjectsCategory(projectsCategory: Object): Observable<Object> {
  console.log("Submitting data service")
  return this.apiService.post(this.baseUrl, projectsCategory);
}


post(path,object_var): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<Response>(this.url+path,object_var, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

How can i fetch the id.. if there is some other method then  please help me with that method

Comment: Remove {observe: 'response'} from your post

Comment: on removing {observe: 'response'} function is returning null response

Comment: So what is the server actually returning? See network tab..

Comment: it is saying failed to load response data